# Export C #defines as shell variables

Tags: c, shell, environment-variables, c-preprocessor, header-files

In my project, a number of paths to various directories, files and other components of the system are stored as `#define`s in a `filenames.h`, a file included by all that need them. It works well for all the various binaries generated by compilation, but the project also includes a few shell scripts that use the same paths. Currently this means that as a path changes, all I have to do is edit `filenames.h` and recompile to get the set of executables to understand the new path, but I have to edit each shell script by hand.

So the question is, how to make the `#defines` into shell variables, for example generating some `filenames.sh` script that would be called from other scripts to initialize them. So for example:

```
#define TMP_PATH      "/ait/tmp/"
#define SYNCTMZFILE   TMP_PATH "sync_tmz"
```

would create

```
TMP_PATH="/ait/tmp/"
SYNCTMZFILE="/ait/tmp/sync_tmz"
```

Of course it would be possible to write a **C** program that creates it (even prints it out to stdout and then to execute it in backticks in the shell) but I'd prefer a simpler, more robust method, say, writing a half-C half-shell like thing that run through `cpp` would create the right output, or something alike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your Makefile:

```
filenames.sh: filenames.h
        awk '/^#define/{print;printf "_%s=%s\n",$2,$2}' $< \
        | cpp -P \
        | sed 's/^_//;s/" "//;' > $@
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't do a very good job of compound statements like in the second #define.

Answer (score 1):

The reverse -- keeping the master as a shell script and generating an header from that -- would be easier.  If your header is very stylized, you can write a shell script (or use awk/sed/perl/...) to parse it and generate the shell fragment.

Answer (score 0):

If you build your program using `make` and the shell scripts are executed by `make` as part of your build process, you could turn it around:

- Single-source the variables in your `Makefile`.
- Export them to the environment for the shell scripts.
- Pass them to the C compiler as command line options. (This assumes your compiler supports the [`-D` parameter](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.3/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) or something similar.)

Example (untested):

```
export TMP_PATH := /ait/tmp/
export SYNCTMZFILE := $(TMP_PATH)sync_tmz
CFLAGS += -DTMP_PATH="$(TMP_PATH)" -DSYNCTMZFILE="$(SYNCTMZFILE)"
```

If you don't use `make`, the `-D` option still may be useful to you: you could single-source the variables in a shell script instead of in a header file.

Comment: CFLAGS like that may not rebuild objects for incremental compilation when paths change. Depends on the makefile. Maybe better to generate a C header from Make or a script it calls.